# How can I downgrade a glibc version?

Tags: linux, rpm, glibc

I upgraded glibc for a reason that isn't around anymore so I want to downgrade it. The stupid thing is a lot of programs rely on glibc at the moment. I still have the 2.4 version on the system as the command below shows, but I'm not able to delete the 2.9 version.

```
# rpm -qa | grep  glibc
glibc-32bit-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-locale-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-locale-32bit-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-info-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-devel-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-2.9-2.9
glibc-i18ndata-2.4-31.74.1
glibc-devel-32bit-2.4-31.74.1
```

I've tried `rpm -e glibc-2.9-2.9` but the system just tells me that a huge amount of stuff depends on glibc. So I was wondering if *I* can somehow set the 2.4 version to default or something similar and then remove the 2.9 version.

Comment: What's wrong with having it?

Comment: since i did the upgrade my yast doesn't work anymore. I receive this error : `warning: the qt frontend is installed but does not work
warning: the ncurses frontend is installed but does not work
You need to install yast2-ncurses to use the YaST2 text mode interface
`

Comment: plus now i think it has something to do with this other problem i'm having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675725/gcc-error-while-configuring-apache-2-2-21

Comment: you don't have glibc-2.4-2.4 installed from the list of packages you showed. If you remove the 2.9 version your system won't have a glibc library anymore, which is _bad_. I guess your programs are not working because you have some glibc-* package at version 2.4 and some other at version 2.9. Did you install version 2.9 from package manager or from a custom rpm?

Comment: Right, this is tricky.  After kernel glibc is probably the most important package on the system, because it creates a layer between the kernel and rest of the userland.  On the top of that it contains the dynamic linker.  Which means without it only statically linked application will work.  Linux system is probably unusable without it.  You seem to have the main subpackage glibc of different version than the rest of the subpackages.  You have to either upgrade glibc or downgrade rest of the glibc* packages.

Comment: Btw, when downgrading, list all individual subpackages which you want to downgrade to yum.  From what I remember yum is notoriously bad at performing downgrades.  Do not rely on it calculating deps for you.  That works nice for upgrades.

Comment: downgrading glibc can be very dangerous as system could be crash. glibc packages are critical kernel packages in every aspects. before doing any upgrade or downgrade activity on glibc make sure you've taken proper OS backup

Answer (score 7):

There are much simpler ways to downgrade the glibc as well. For example, `yum` will calculate all of the needed dependencies for you with a

```
yum downgrade glibc\*
```

command. But beware: downgrading glibc is always a really dangerous trick, and it is so on every system.

Glibc on version 2.4 and 2.9 had already very good compatibility between them, I suggest for you the best option were is your 2.9 left.